# Hide certain element from the user control that contains it, but still display it on web form which contains the user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I asked this awhile ago, and got a few responses, but ultimately decided the solution I had picked won't work.

I have a master page which has a content placeholder that loads a user control.

Additionally I have a web form, which is independant of the master page, that contains a placeholder for this same user control. (thus we are loading the same content, just in an independant web form).

We use this 'version' of this content as the printable version.

I have added new functionality to the user control which stores its purpose in a literal. I need to hide this literal from being displayed on the user control, but need it to display on the 'printable' webform.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two different stylesheets, one with media 'print' one with media 'screen'.  Hide the content you don't want when you are on the screen and show it for printing.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: Will this still allow the literal to be visible when displaying the webform for printing, or will it only be visible once printed?